# Get state vectors in qiskit at any time in a circuit created with initialize() and decompose()

Tags: qiskit

How can I get the state vectors at any point in the circuit if after these instructions it points to end.

```
qc.initialize(psi)
qc2=qc
for d in range(20):
    qc2=qc2.decompose()
```

If I use `Statevector.from_instruction(qc2)` gives only the last, and `*QuantumCircuit.get_instructions(name)* does not return the entire circuit instructions ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the statevector at any point by inserting a [`SaveStatevector`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.library.SaveStatevector.html) instruction at this point. Then simulating the circuit.

And you can get the list of instructions in the circuit by using `QuantumCircuit.data` attribute.

For example, this code snippet will insert a `SaveStatevector` instruction after the third instruction in your circuit:

```
index = 3
_inst = SaveStatevector(num_qubits)
qc2.data.insert(index, [_inst, qc2.qubits, None])
```

And this is how to insert a `SaveStatevector` after each instruction:

```
from qiskit.providers.aer.library import SaveStatevector

num_qubits = qc2.num_qubits
for index in range(len(qc2.data) - 1, -1, -1):
    _inst = SaveStatevector(num_qubits, label = 'psi_' + str(index))
    qc2.data.insert(index, [_inst, qc2.qubits, None])
```

This is another example which shows how to insert a `SaveStatevector` instruction after each layer. This time we are using [`save_statevector`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.save_statevector.html) method:

```
from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag, dag_to_circuit

dag = circuit_to_dag(qc2)
new_dag = dag.copy_empty_like()

for index, layer in enumerate(dag.layers()):
    circ = dag_to_circuit(layer['graph'])
    circ.save_statevector('psi_' + str(index))
    layer['graph'] = circuit_to_dag(circ)
    new_dag.compose(layer['graph'])

qc2 = dag_to_circuit(new_dag)
```

Now, simulate the circuit to get the statevectors:

```
from qiskit import Aer
from IPython.display import display

simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = simulator.run(qc2).result()
for key, value in result.data().items():
    print(key)
    display(value.draw('latex'))
```

---

**Note**

Starting from version 0.37, [`QuantumCircuit.decompose()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose.html) supports a new parameter, `reps`, which can be used to specify number of times the circuit should be decomposed. So, instead of these two lines of codes:

```
for d in range(20):
    qc2=qc2.decompose()
```

you can simply use:

```
qc2.decompose(reps = 20)
```