# get.statevector() error: Failed to load qobj: Duplicate key "statevector" in save instruction

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm building a mini tutorial to introduce the construction of composite systems using qiskit.  While doing so I am demonstrating multiple ways to construct and view the statevector, but I have come across an error which I'm hoping to circumvent.

In the initial cells I have created and displayed a simple two qubit circuit, qc, with Hadamard gates on each qubit.  I then have the following two cells to show two different ways to simulate and display the resulting statevector.

```
svsim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
qc.save_statevector()
qobj = assemble(qc)
final_state = svsim.run(qobj).result().get_statevector()

#Now to display it
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(final_state, prefix="|\psi^{AB} \\rangle = ")
```

The second version is

```
from qiskit import execute
backend=Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result=execute(qc,backend).result()
out_state=result.get_statevector()
array_to_latex(out_state, prefix="|\psi^{AB} \\rangle = ")
```

Individually they both work to display an identical statevector, but running them in sequence gives the error: Failed to load qobj: Duplicate key "statevector" in save instruction..  My understanding is that even though my second one does not explicitly use `save_statevector()`, it still saves it as a part of the source coding.  As a result I then have two statevectors saved and I need to somehow specify which one I am wanting to 'get'?

I've tried specifying an experiment in my second `get_statevector()` by using `experiment=` as a parameter, but nothing I've set it equal to has worked.  Any ideas?

Note: I do know that if I simply switch the order of these it will work as the `save_statevector()` will update to just the one that has been saved preventing the error, but I'm hoping there might be another way to do this either by applying another `save_statevector()` in the second input cell, or perhaps by somehow specifying the `experiment =` accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`save_statevector()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.save_statevector.html) method to add `SaveStatevector` instruction to your circuit, you can specify a label. After circuit execution, the `Statevector` will be saved to [`Result.data`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.data.html) dictionary where the key will be that label. If you don't specify a label, `statevector` will be used by default.

And when you simulate your circuit using `statevector_simulator`, the result will be saved, similarly, to [`Result.data`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.data.html) dictionary. The key this time also will be `statevector`.

Clearly, this will cause an issue if you add `SaveStatevector` instruction to your circuit then use `statevector_simulator` to execute it.
A simple workaround is to call `save_statevector()` with a label:

```
qc.save_statevector(label = 'sv')
```

then retrieve the value using this label:

```
final_state = svsim.run(qobj).result().data()['sv']
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I needed!  Thank you!  I should have a chance to try it out later today!

Comment: Will using the save_statevector() with labels like this then allow me to save multiple statevectors along a single circuit?

Comment: Yes! See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27923/9474) for some examples.